# How to detect a name in .txt then write and extend it in another file

Tags: python, latex

I am currently automating latex by using python.

The codes should allow the user to write stuff in .txt file and python can read the contents from .txt then to write them on .tex, finally, latex can compile the .tex to PDF

Everything was fine until a figure needed to be put in. Because there are certain codes needed to put a figure in latex.

For example:

The user writes a paragraph in .txt as follows:

```
Lorem Lorem Lorem
```

Then he specifies a figure he wants to use by typing the name.

```
somefigure.png
```

How can I turn this to .tex by using python codes :

```
Lorem Lorem Lorem 

\begin{figure}[H]

\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{somefigure}

\caption{somefigure}

\end{figure}
```

The difficulties are to detect the name and extent it in latex format.

I have tried:

```
with open("INTRODUCTION.txt") as INTRODUCTIONTXT:
    with open("INTRODUCTION.tex", "w") as INTRODUCTIONTEX:
        for lines in INTRODUCTIONTXT:
        INTRODUCTIONTEX.write(lines)


INTROFIG = open("INTRODUCTION.txt")
if "PNP.name.PNP" in INTROFIG:

print("\begin{figure}[H]\n\centering")
```

I will be grateful for any answer!

Comment: StackOverflow is not a free coding service. What have you tried so far? What issues do you encounter (errors/bad results)?

Comment: Thank you, I am sorry If I feel like seeking for free service. I am totally new to python, which again sounds like some stupid excuse. with open("INTRODUCTION.txt") as INTRODUCTIONTXT:
    with open("INTRODUCTION.tex", "w") as INTRODUCTIONTEX:
        for lines in INTRODUCTIONTXT:
            INTRODUCTIONTEX.write(lines)
        

INTROFIG = open("INTRODUCTION.txt")
if "PNP.name.PNP" in INTROFIG:

print("\begin{figure}[H]\n\centering") That's pretty much I have tried

Comment: You can edit your original post and format it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hopefully this untested code will do what you want

```
filename = 'INTRODUCTION'

# This is a raw (note the r - ignores \ escapes) multiline string.
# The {{ and }} become { and } and {0} will be replaced by the first argument
# of the format method.
figure_block = r'''\begin{{figure}}[H]

\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{{{0}}}

\caption{{{0}}}

\end{{figure}}

'''

with open(filename + '.txt') as txtfile:
    with open(filename + '.tex', 'w') as texfile:
        for line in txtfile:
            stripped_line = line.strip()  # remove white-space either side
            if stripped_line.endswith('.png'):  # self-explanatory -- yay python
                 texfile.write(figure_block.format(stripped_line))
            else:
                 texfile.write(line)
```

Comment: Thank you so much man!! Thanks for the promp answer. I will try it out! Cheers

Comment: Hi, Just want to say thank you again! your code is so helpful and making much sense to me now! With a bit of modification, it's been able to create the caption in latex too. Thanks a lot